# Regarding migration

Tags: discussion, migration

How do questions get migrated? Why is it an anonymous process (afaics)?

Comment: Please also see [this question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1739/flagging-questions-as-off-topic).

Answer (score 4):

It's not anonymous, though a little hidden; for example, on [this migrated question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13113/good-latex-book-for-math-beginner), if you click on the link in the "migrated from [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26102/good-latex-book-for-math-beginner?noredirect=1)" label, you get taken to the original question with the list of users that voted to close <s>(migrate?)</s> it.

Comment: Ah. So I voted to migrate it?! :P

Comment: @Mariano: You didn't?! :p

Comment: I voted to close. I did not know that counted for migration, too. (It was really impossible that the question was *not* a duplicate of some other question on the tex site...)

Comment: @Mariano: unfortunately voting to close has the property that the reason chosen by a plurality (which in this case was me) is the reason displayed.

Comment: My understanding is that once a question is migrated, it is up to the other community's users to decide what to do with it. In this case, it was closed as duplicate. But in doing so, we now produced a connected path from this migrated question to its target at TeX.SE and then to its duplicate at TeX.SE which gives the answer the OP sought. So all in all I think the system is working as intended.

Answer (score 4):

Migration happens in one of two ways:

- If a question is closed, if a majority of the close votes were off-topic—belongs on some other site, it gets migrated, and the message says it was migrated be everyone who voted to close (regardless of the close reason each person voted for—this is the same as the behavior for any close reason)
- A moderator migrates it